# Extract text from a CLOB datatype field in Oracle table

Tags: json, oracle, oracle11g

Can some one please advise how to extract text from the field below? It is a JSON file which is stored as a CLOB datatype field in an Oracle table.

The field name is `Rules` and its value is as below:

```
{
   "condition":[
      {
         "name":"",
         "property":"ipaddress",
         "type":"range",
         "operator":"range",
         "start":"2.117.11.1",
         "end":"2.117.11.254"
      }
   ],
   "operator":{
      "property":"or"
   },
   "outcome":{
      "name":"BRSBRS",
      "reason":"Site was created on Fri Apr 20 2018 09:45:46 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylighttime)"
   }
}
```

I want to extract the two IP address from above in two different fields as shown below:

[image]

Comment: That looks like a JSON document, except it is not (not a valid one, anyway). There should be a colon after "condition". Is that a typo on your part, or is the string really missing it? If the string is not a valid JSON document, then you will need to use regular expressions; it will be a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you had a typo in your string, and it is, in fact, a valid JSON document (meaning: you are missing a colon after `"condition"`, you can use the `json_table()` function, available since Oracle 12.1.

```
create table tbl (id number primary key, rules clob);
insert into tbl (id, rules) 
  select 1001,  '{"condition":[{"name":"","property":"ipaddress","type":"range","operator":"range","start":"2.117.11.1","end":"2.117.11.254"}],"operator":{"property":"or"},"outcome": {"name":"BRSBRS","reason":"Site was created on Fri Apr 20 2018 09:45:46 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylighttime)"}}'
  from   dual;

select id, start_ip_address, end_ip_address
from   tbl,
       json_table(rules format json, '$.condition[*]'
           columns start_ip_address varchar2(19) path '$.start',
                   end_ip_address   varchar2(19) path '$.end'
      )
;

  ID  START_IP_ADDRESS  END_IP_ADDRESS
----  ----------------  ----------------
1001  2.117.11.1        2.117.11.254
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and response, I built the SQL below and I got the following error

**SQL:**

`SELECT SITE_ID, START_IP_ADDRESS, END_IP_ADDRESS 
FROM EXTRACT_IP_ADDR, 
     json_table(RULES format json, '$.condition[*]'
                columns start_ip_address varchar2(100) path '$.start',
                end_ip_address varchar2(100) path '$.end');`

**_Error_:
_ORA-00933_: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 16**

Is there anything I'm missing here, please advise?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g version, is that a concern, heard 11g doesn't support Jason?
If that's true, please advise how I can work around this scenario for a solution?

Comment: @user10531062 - That is definitely a problem; there is no JSON support before Oracle version 12.1. This is why it's so important to state your Oracle version with **every** question you ask here (or anywhere else). The best choice is to upgrade to at least Oracle 12.1. Otherwise you will need to solve with regular expressions; the solution will be prone to errors no matter how carefully you write and test it.